# Select tag option depending on another select tag selected value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form in which are two select tags used. I want second select tag's options to be dependent on the selected value of the first select tag. Please I need help. It can be in either php or javascript. This is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
<i>*All fields marked with asterisk are required!</i><br>
<li>
<br>
<select name="service_type">
<option value="" selected>*Select Service Type</option>
<option value="Business Service">Busines</option>
<option value="Research Service">Sales</option>
<option value="Training Service">Typing</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>
<br>
<select name="service_detail">
<option value="" selected>*Select Service Detail</option>
<?php
if (selected = 'business') {
<option value="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>
<option value="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>
} else if(selected = 'sales') {
<option value="drugs">drugs</option>
<option value="books">books</option>
} else if(selected = 'typing') {
<option value="story">story</option>
<option value="news">news</option>
}
?>
</select> 
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried something to resolve the problem?

Comment: Did you [*search*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dependent+select) for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#serviceType").on("change", function(){
        var val = $("#serviceType").val();
        $('#serviceDetail').empty().append('<option val="">*Select Service Detail</option>');
        if(val == "Business Service"){
            $('#serviceDetail').append('<option val="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>');
            $('#serviceDetail').append('<option val="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>');
        }
        else if(val == "Research Service"){
            $('#serviceDetail').append('<option val="drugs">drugs</option>');
            $('#serviceDetail').append('<option val="books">books</option>');
        }
        else if(val == "Training Service"){
            $('#serviceDetail').append('<option val="story">story</option>');
            $('#serviceDetail').append('<option val="news">news</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
<i>*All fields marked with asterisk are required!</i><br>
<li>
<br>
<select name="service_type" id="serviceType">
<option value="" selected>*Select Service Type</option>
<option value="Business Service">Busines</option>
<option value="Research Service">Sales</option>
<option value="Training Service">Typing</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>
<br>
<select name="service_detail" id="serviceDetail">
<option value="" selected>*Select Service Detail</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87cd8tms/2/

Comment: how does this :<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> come into play

Comment: @johngraham It's the jQuery library file. This must be included.

Comment: can i download it and include it manually since my site works offline

Comment: anyway i jux added the javascript unto the page directly and it works....Thanks a lot

Comment: @johngraham Ya. You should.

Comment: @johngraham if it's working, then make it as resolved. Thanks :)